# Loop through all sockets in socket.io v1

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, socket.io, socket.io-1.0

k so I try for 1 hour now and it still not working

I want to get id of every socket.io user so I tried this:

```
var socket_list = new Array();

io.on('connection', function (socket) {... socket_list.push(socket); ...}
```

then

```
for(var soc in socket_list) { console.log(soc.id); }
```

but it still undefined. how to fix? thanks

it looks simple but just not working

also tried console.log(socket_list) and it worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`socket_list` is an array. So use an appropriate loop:

```
for(var i = 0; i < socket_list.length; i++) { 
    console.log(socket_list[i].id); 
}
```

Answer (score -1):

This is how I did it:

```
io.sockets.sockets.forEach(function (socket) {
  console.log(socket.id);
});
```